# Django: Add related objects that are part of a set

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, many-to-many

Apologies for the terrible title, I'm not sure how best to phrase this.

I have more complex products that can have multiple options stored with in option sets, for example:

```
Shirts:
    Sizes:
        Small
        Medium
        Large
```

Obviously the same shirt can be had in a Small, Medium or Large size but I want our admins to be able to add extra sizes (or other options) at a later date.

To express these I am using the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = RichTextField(blank=True)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    left_image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    right_image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

# A container that can hold multiple ProductOptions
class ProductOptionSet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ProductOption(models.Model):
    option_set = models.ForeignKey(ProductOptionSet, related_name="test")
    option_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    option_slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='A system friendly version of the value')

# Inherited from my CMS system.
class ShirtProduct(Product):
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(ProductOption, related_name="shirt_size")
```

I am looking to save these options based on some simple strings of information e.g key="size" and size = "medium"  in the ShirtProduct save() method.

Currently I have the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
[...]
    product_options = {
        'sizes': 'medium',
        'colour': 'blue'
    }
    for key, value in product_options.items():
        if key == "sizes":
            option = ProductOption.objects.get(option_slug=value)
            self.sizes.add(option)

    super(ShirtProduct, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However this appears to do nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: You have inherited your `ShirtProduct` model from `Product`, then could you show your `Product` model? and which model's save method is this?? Could you be more specific?

Comment: That's impossible to answer without knowing where `key` comes from. And why are you using `is` to compare?

Comment: Apologies, I've made some edits that should help clarify things and fix my mistake.